# Why didn't Londo Mollari have any children, given that he had 3 wives, was a great romantic and was Emperor in his later years?

Tags: babylon-5, londo-mollari

Londo Mollari had 3 wives. It was as though he kept a harem. Granted that he didn't seem to love his wives, he still had his sexual needs and he should still sleep with them occasionally. An accidental "by-product" is likely to happen. Besides, Londo was a great romantic. In one of the episodes in Season 1, he had a touching romance with a dancer who betrayed him. Yet, Londo sought to protect the dancer. Furthermore, he later became Emperor. As Emperor, there will be plenty of opportunities to make love with women of his choice in his kingdom. Even more so as Emperor, he had a duty to the Empire to produce an heir to succeed him even if he is gay which he obviously was not.

Why doesn't Londo have any children? This seems like a great mystery to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a younger man with three wives, Londo spent most of his time avoiding them. Having a child would likely have ended any such ability to treat them as distantly as he liked, not to mention give whichever wife bore the child that much more power within the family.

As an older emperor, he actually did rekindle a romance with Timov. Once it was very very clear the Drakh were paying extra attention to people he cared about - not to mention sex would require his shoulder spy as witness - he pushed her away to keep her safe. No further relationships were started from that point forward.

Comment: Is that romance shown in one of the books? I still haven't read them or even got my hands on them.

Comment: @Dranon - yeah it is. I'm on mobile or I would detail the answer, but both Muriel and Timov are in the Centauri trilogy. Timov in particular respects the position of emperor while disrespecting Londo, so they fit together quite well for a time.

Comment: I always did like Timov. Thank you for clarifying.